# How to secure my sensitive data of my static website in Webpack bundle js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, static

I am working on a project where I will generate a **static website** (index.html), where `bundle.js` is included, and send this static website (index.html) to the customer like a "report". And here is the workflow:

1st: I have the data that I need to import in my frontend React.js code in order to display it on the html webpage. (some `json` file)

2nd: I will import these data in my javascript code (e.g. i`mport data from "../../../data/queried_data.json"`)

3rd: I will do `npm run build` to use `webpack` to bundle my frontend code in to `index.html` and `bundle.js` to my `dist` folder

4th: I will upload this `bundle.js` to AWS S3 and make it's address publicly shared. Then I will change my `<script>` tag in my `index.html` to `<script src="http://my-bucket.s3.amasonaws.com/fodler/**bundle.js**">`

5th: After changing `script` tag in my `index.html` file, I can sent this `index.html`, a static website, to my customer. And my customer will be able to see all the data, the UI, and clicking around pages in my `index.html`

---

The trickiest thing is, the aforementioned `json data` for my front-end code to rendered and display on the static website, this data should only available to be seen by designated customer. However, those data imported to my front-end code are also bundled to the `bundle.js` file. This static website(index.html) would work for my customers only if their `bundle.js` are uploaded and publicly shared on `aws s3`. Therefore, since now the associated `aws s3` folder (containing customers' `bundle.js`）is public, the sensitive data will be included in the `bundle.js` and those sensitive data will be exposed somehow. It's not secure because I don't want customer A (`index-A.html`) would be able to see the data of customer B (`index-B.html`) (I believe customer A can go to the public `aws s3` address and trace back to other customers' `bundle.js` which includes their sensitive data somehow?).

Conclusion and question:

Noted, this is a portable static website that I will be sending to the designated customer. How do I make sure customers will only be able to see their own data and not each other's data? Without the usage of backend server.

Please help if you have thoughts or any suggestion, I am desperate

---

Here are something for your reference:

- Project folder structure:

[Click to see image of folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vgag.png)

- my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      Change "src" to aws s3's bundle.js before sending to customer
    -->
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "antd": "^4.3.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "test": "echo \\\"Error: no test specified\\\" && exit 1",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

- My `webpack.prod.js`

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "./",
    filename: "vadvisor-bundle.js",
  },
});
```

- My `webpack.common.js`

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".less"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
      filename: "index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: I received two suggestions from my friend: 

1. somehow include all the code in `bundle.js`, so  that nobody's `index.html` will reference their `bundle.js` in `<script src="">`

2. having those sensitive `json` data `embedded` in the `index.html`, so that only the the customer who receive their `index.html` can see their own sensitive data, and won't able to see others'.

No sure if these methods would work though. Please suggest~~~

Comment: You can secure individual aws folders with passwords to control access.

Comment: @smartdroid Thanks for your quick reply!!! That was my first thought too. I may being silly here, but, are you saying I would use bash script or something to provide customers' credentials to their `index.html` so that their `index.html` can securely access to their `bundle.js`? Any suggestion on how to implement that? Many thanks!

Comment: @smartdroid Are you sure that AWS S3 takes .htaccess files into account?

Comment: @ZheXu Yes, those two suggestions from your friend are both proper, and much easier to set up than access control on the server.

Comment: @Bergi - you are right. S3 does not support htaccess. comment deleted.

Comment: @smartdroid thanks for putting effort and giving it a thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is a portable static website that I will be sending to the designated customer.

This doesn't sound very portable to me to have the website consist of an offline `.html` file and an online `.js` file. Choose either, not a mix.

- Online solution: upload both the html file and the js file(s) and use serverside protection with username/password. There are myriads of ways to do it. Then send your customer the url and his credentials.
- Offline solution: send both the html file and the bundled js file to the customer, make them place both in the same folder, and use a relative link to embed the script.

If you want to have a single artifact to send to the customer, there's an even simpler solution: just embed the script contents directly in an inline `<script>` tag. You might even use your build system to do that automatically through templating. Alternatively, embed only the sensitive customer-specific JSON data in the html file and link an online script to process it, cutting down file size and allowing updates to the script. (But make sure that you are the only one who can update the script, and that it is loaded with https, so nobody else can manipulate the script to extract the data when the customer opens their file).

Comment: These are some brilliant insights, THANKS. My followup question are: 1. As for the "one artifact sending to customer" method, do you have any suggestion on how to implement it? I mean I familiar with using webpack to bundle my js and include it in the `script` tag, but I'm not sure what's the tool/method that help me "stuff" my bundled js code in `script` tag ( like you mentioned "`You might even use your build system to do that automatically through templating`", can you elaborate it a little bit?). Also in this way, can I still use framework like React for development? Much appreciate!

Comment: Take a look at the [`HtmlWebpackPlugin` options](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options). I haven't looked in detail, but it seems that with the template option you can write a template that takes the script source and outputs inside a script tag.

Comment: Thanks! I was finally able to get this issue resolved using HTMLWebpackPlugin yesterday